# Opening Async Class from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I know this may be simple, and I have seen so many people ask how to open one activity from another, but it does not seem to be working for me. I have one class, "NewInstallReceiver", that extends BroadcastReceiver, and another class, "SendToClient" that extents AsyncTask. I am creating a string variable called "applicationName" in NewInstallReceiver that I want to pass to SendToClient.

The problem is that I am not sure if I am correctly passing the variable because my SendToClient class never seems to open in the first place. I know this because the print statement that I have at the top of my Async class, never prints in my android monitor. **How do I call my Async class from my BroadcastReceiver class and pass the string variable?**

**NewInstallReceiver which creates a variable to be passed to SendToClient**

```
public class NewInstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo ai;
    try {


        ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart(), 0);


    } catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        ai = null;
    }

    final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
    Log.d("Application NAME", "" + applicationName);

    // This line should open "SendToClient" and pass the variable "applicationName"

    new SendToClient().execute(applicationName);
}
}
```

I have also tried adding this line of code to NewInstallReceiver, but it did not work either.

```
Intent intent_2 = new Intent(context, SendToClient.class);
    context.getApplicationContext().startService(intent_2);
```

**SendToClient which should receive the variable applicationName**

```
public class SendToClient extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    Log.d("Entered AsyncTask", "");

    String applicationName = params[0];

    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Did you checked first whether `Log.d("Application NAME", "" + applicationName);` is printed ?

Comment: @ShadabAnsari yes, I have put print statements throughout NewInstallReceiver, and they all print, including the one for "Application NAME".

Comment: Change your log statements to `Log.d("tag_name", .....);` so that every log statement comes under the same filter "tag_name". Then you'll be to identify whether you have all the logs printed or not.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari wow! I feel really dumb! I thought it might be something with the print statement, but I didn't know how to change it. Thanks so much! turns out it was working.